# My first LinearLayout onclick works while rest others not. why?

Tags: android, xml-layout

I am working on a big UI to show the detail of the user form. I want that if the user clicks on the `LinearLayout` containing the phone number `TextView`. I want to make a call `intent`. I have added the `onClick()` attribute to all the `LinearLayout`s. But only the first one works while others does not any explanations will be appreciated.

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="10dp" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButtonMSG1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#f8f3c2"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/msg" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/ll1"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButtonMSGMobile"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewMobile1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:text="Small Text"
                        android:textColor="#790202"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewCperson1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                        android:text="Cperson1"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="#E14343" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView201"
                    android:layout_width="0.1dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:background="#8E6364"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="2dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView51"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0.2dp"
                    android:background="#8E6364"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="10dp" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/ll2"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButtonMSGHome"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewMobile2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:text="Small Text"
                    android:duplicateParentState="true"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#790202" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewCperson2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                    android:text="Cperson2"
                    android:duplicateParentState="true"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="#E14343" />

                </LinearLayout>
                 <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView202"
                    android:layout_width="0.2dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:background="#8E6364"
                     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButtonMSG2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#f8f3c2"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/msg" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```

`LinearLayout` with id *ll1* works for `onClick()` Event, while the *ll2* and rest others does not work. I dont know why this happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure for each layout you do the following:

```
LinearLayout ll1 = (LinearLayout )findViewById(R.id.ll1);
ll1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {      
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Do stuff here     
    }
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to simply declare the `onClick` property in your XML - this will avoid you calling `setOnClickListener` for each view. This can be done like so:

```
<LinearLayout
    ...
    android:onClick="doSomething" >
```

Then, in your Java code you will need a public method named `doSomething` that accepts a parameter with type `View`:

```
public void doSomething(View view) {
// React to click here
}
```

Note, you do not have to do anything with the `view` parameter if you don't want/need to.